# Substitutions for 'which' and 'for which' that maintain the sentence's meaning

Tags: word-choice

I am having a bit of a problem trying to substitute the words *which* and *for* without changing too much the meaning/flow of the sentence. I have tried the thesaurus, synonyms, etc with no luck.

> I achieved a strong 2:1 in X at Y University and excelled in modules studied during my final year, *for* many of *which* I received a First. This included a Financial Analysis and Control module *for which* I attained a strong First (72%) *for* a financial performance analysis of the Z Company.

"A First" (UK Grade) is like an "A" in the United States; I know it can be kind of bizarre when reading if you're not used to it.

Comment: Really going to town here, Standback.

Comment: This is an older question. It's been bumped by the system because it's been retagged, as per [this](http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/q/534/26) meta post.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Will this do?

> I achieved a strong 2:1 in X at Y University and excelled in modules studied during my final year, *and received a First in many of them*. *They* included a Financial Analysis and Control module *in* which I attained a strong First (72%) for a financial performance analysis of Company Z.

You basically have to rephrase to get rid of "whiches".  Also, there is nothing wrong with using *for which* in moderation.  I only removed one "which" because the second by itself was just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I like drɱ65 δ's advice for the first sentence. For the second, try:

> In my Financial Analysis and Control module I
>   attained a strong First (72%) for a financial performance analysis of
>   the Z Company.

This not only removes the *which*, but also leaves the sentence with a stronger main verb--*attained* instead of the wimpier *included.*